# Picking emoji fonts in Neovim?

Tags: linux, fonts, emoji, neovim

How to set the font used for emojis in Neovim?

More specifically, how do I set it to **Noto Monochrome Emoji Font**?

- https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/tree/main/fonts
- https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Emoji

Comment: You can set the font inside your terminal settings and you should be good to go. Or do you want it only inside NeoVim?